# Insert special characters with dbms_store.insertXML

Tags: xml, plsql

I am trying to insert some sanitised XML into a table using dbms_store.insertXML. The insert needs to store special characters rather than their escaped equivilant.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_test
(
   key_num NUMBER,
   value_desc VARCHAR2 (1000)
);
```

Example function using DBMS_XMLSTORE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_insertxml
(
   pi_xmldoc IN CLOB,
   pi_tablename IN VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   v_ctx_type DBMS_XMLSTORE.ctxtype;
   v_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- Set the context to the table to be inserted into
   v_ctx_type := DBMS_XMLSTORE.newcontext (pi_tablename);

   -- Insert document
   v_rows := DBMS_XMLSTORE.insertxml (v_ctx_type, pi_xmldoc);

   -- Close the context
   DBMS_XMLSTORE.closecontext (v_ctx_type);

   RETURN v_rows;
END fn_insertxml;
```

Example Code:

```
DECLARE
   k_injected_input CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (4000) := q'[<![CDATA[x]]></VALUE_DESC><KEY_NUM>-1</KEY_NUM><VALUE_DESC><![CDATA[example text]';
   k_xml_doc CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (4000) := q'[<ROWSET><ROW num='0'><KEY_NUM><![CDATA[1]]></KEY_NUM><VALUE_DESC><![CDATA[%s]]></VALUE_DESC></ROW></ROWSET>]';

   v_row_num NUMBER;
   v_sanitised_input varchar2(4000);
   v_xml_doc VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   --Sanitised input
   v_sanitised_input := DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (k_injected_input, DBMS_XMLGEN.entity_encode);

   --If I insert this as it is, the sanitized input is stored
   v_xml_doc := REPLACE (k_xml_doc, '%s', v_sanitised_input);
   v_row_num := fn_insertxml (v_xml_doc, 'XML_TEST');

   --If I attempt to decode the xml it is open to XML injection (key_num is set to -1)
   v_sanitised_input := DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (v_sanitised_input, DBMS_XMLGEN.entity_decode);
   v_xml_doc := REPLACE (k_xml_doc, '%s', v_sanitised_input);
   v_row_num := fn_insertxml (v_xml_doc, 'XML_TEST');
END;
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

In the unlikely event that anyone else runs into this. DBMS_XMLSTORE.insertxml will convert escaped characters back to their original value as long as they arn't wrapped in CDATA.